# Windows 10: Second Monitor Intermittently Fails to be Detected

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

PC specs:

OS:  Windows 10 Home, 64bit; 
CPU: Intel Core i5 25003.30GHz; 
RAM: 32G; 
Monitors:
- HP ProDisplay P221 LED Backlit Monitor, DVI-D connection 
- Dell U3415W, HDMI connection; 
Graphics Card: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970

Problem:
Upgraded the existing Windows 7 to Windows 10.  Both monitors worked fine for months.  Over the last month, the Dell U3415W monitor goes into standby mode after my PC goes into sleep mode.  The display setting no longer sees the Dell monitor.  Doesn't matter if it's the primary or secondary monitor.  When it first happened, I rolled back the driver for the graphics card.  Did not resolve the issue.  Did all of the usual other tasks that I would recommend initially.

Updated the most current NVIDIA driver, version 22.21.13.8541.
Went to display settings to see if it would detect the second monitor as a routine check (didn't).
Scanned for new hardware (still undetected).
Looked in device manager to see if this might have reverted to an "unknown" device.  None listed.
Checked the physical connection to make sure it wasn't loose.  It's not.

I can turn off the monitor and power it back on.  There is a 50/50 chance the monitor will be detected.  If not, I have to reboot.  Or I can disable the graphics card and then re-enable it and will *usual* detect it.

When cycling the power on the monitor, the Dell monitor remains black.  However, I know the PC recognizes the monitor is there as I am able to move my mouse cursor across to the Dell monitor.  Some applications that are open move from the HP monitor to the Dell monitor.  The Dell monitor remains black and I'm unable to see any of the apps.  Monitor still shows in standby mode.  I turn off the Dell monitor and all of my apps move back to my HP monitor as it becomes the only monitor.

I want to find a solution so I am not having to manipulate my system to get my second monitor to show up.  The other posts don't deal with intermittent detection issues.

Would appreciate it if someone knew the resolution or could provide additional troubleshooting steps.

Thank you.

Comment: Completely anecdotal but, I suspect the NVidia drivers. I've been having similar issues with a new build

Comment: Posted the same question on NVidia forum and with M.S. tech support.  Since this worked for a long time with no issues, hard to tell if this is a NVidia driver issue or Windows update.  It's not specific to the Dell monitor.  Actually found another post where someone had the same problem, with no resolution posted.  I'm leaning towards agreeing with you.  Also, considered doing a Windows recovery, but it's been too long and I can't go back to a date before this issue began.

Comment: Maybe not just an NVidia issue.  Found another post where a user has the same problem using a Radeon HD 7850 graphics card on Windows 7 64bit.

Comment: added a win 10 to my linux machine, dual boot. dual monitors work perfect on linux but on win 10 the second monitor gets dropped often, and always on sleep or hibernate. so this is a windows and windows driver issue, not hardware.

Answer (score 0):

OK this isn't going to be a full answer but I don't have the rep to leave a comment. Have you tried swapping the monitors over so the problem monitor is your primary and see if the problem persists? If it does then you could probably safely assume the issue is in this monitor, but if the problem now switches to the other monitor then you know that the problem is in your pc. 
Again sorry for not a full answer but I thought this would help!

Comment: I understand.  I appreciate the feedback.  Yes, I have.   The problem follows the Dell monitor.  So, in my mind, it's narrowed down to a driver issue with the Dell Monitor on Windows 10.  Trying to reach out to Dell for assistance.  Still looking.  :)

Comment: Do you have a separate pc you could try it with?

Comment: Hmm.  Actually, in the middle of re-building a second PC.  When I get done, I'll try using the Dell on the second PC.